# Does anybody know why the last arg in input_shape must be specied 3 in keras' application?

Tags: image, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, vgg-net

I want to use pre-train Net, such as VGG, ResNet. While in Keras, there must be specified the formate in (w,h,3) in input_shape. If I want to specify the channel to 1, is there have more tricks?

```
conv_vgg = keras.application.VGG16(input_shape=(224,224,3))
```

I want to specify 3 to 1:

```
conv_vgg = keras.application.VGG16(input_shape=(224,224,1))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre-trained networks as trained in imagenet or other image data sets. This means that is trained with RGB images that's why using a pretrained network requires three channels.

If you want to use pre-trained networks for a single channel image you could repeat your channel three times and proceed. (Repeat-copy two more times your 1-channel image, from (224,224,1) shape to (224,224,3) shape (3-channels image).

Comment: Thanks, Ioannis Nasios. If so, is the performance will be affected? more time training? If I use np.zeros() padding the other 2 dimensions is the correct way?

Comment: No, DO NOT use zero padding for other 2 channels. 
This trick is a way to use pre-trained networks for you 1-channel images. Using weights from a pre-trained network speeds things up, make convergence faster and often more accurate.

Comment: Thanks, you have unfrozen my big confuse.